# VLC screen capture using terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, vlc, screen-capture

I'm attempting to capture my screen as video and found VLC to probably be the best solution. What I have to do is capture a specific application using terminal and then stop the capture as well. Right now, I can capture using terminal with the following command:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -I dummy screen:// --screen-fps=25 --quiet --sout "#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb072}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst="Desktop/vlc-output-terminal.mp4"}"
```

That's great, it works. The question is, how do I quit the recording using terminal? Right now, I'm having to do <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the terminal to quit it. I've seen `vlc://quit` online, but I'm not sure how to use that command.

Also, does anyone know if it's possible to capture a specific application using VLC or is the whole screen the only option?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### How to **NOT** quit when recording

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kill process (in this case VLC) with signal `SIGINT`.

`vlc://quit` option will not work when you capture screen because stream is never-ending source.

---

### Right way - [RC (**R**emote **C**ontrol)](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Advanced_Use_of_VLC/#RC_and_RTCI)

You can connect to your VLC using a `TCP socket` or a `UNIX socket`.

- TCP socket

  > To be able to remote connect to your VLC using a TCP socket (telnet-like connetion), use **--rc-host your_host:port**. Then, by connecting (using telnet or netcat) to the host on the given port, you will get the command shell.
- UNIX socket

  > To use a UNIX socket (local socket, this does not work for Windows), use **--rc-unix /path/to/socket**. Commands can then be passed using this UNIX socket.

To enable [remote control](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/rc/) interface for VLC you will need to add options

```
--extraintf rc --rc-quiet
```

---

### How to quit

- TCP socket

  echo quit | nc your_host port
- UNIX socket

  echo quit | nc -U /path/to/socket

  ---

  ### Example

  1. Execute VLC

     ```
     vlc \
     screen:// --one-instance \
     -I dummy --dummy-quiet \
     --extraintf rc \
     --rc-host localhost:8082 \
     --rc-quiet \
     --screen-follow-mouse \
     --screen-mouse-image="mouse_pointer.png" \
     --screen-left=0 --screen-top=0 --screen-width=800 --screen-height=600 \
     --no-video :screen-fps=15 :screen-caching=300 \
     --sout "#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,fps=5,scale=1,acodec=none}:duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='/Videos/screen.mp4'}}"
     ```
  2. Gracefully shutdown VLC

     ```
     echo quit | nc localhost 8082
     ```

     You can also use `Python` code below if you do not have [nc (netcat)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) on your computer.

     ```
     import socket
     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     s.connect(('localhost', 8082))
     s.sendall('quit\n')
     s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
     ```

---

### How to capture specific application

You can't select which application to record but you can specify coordinate, width and height of the subscreen.

[Options](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/screen#Options)

- `--screen-top integer` The top edge coordinate of the subscreen. *Default value: 0*
- `--screen-left integer` The left edge coordinate of the subscreen. *Default value: 0*
- `--screen-width integer` The width of the subscreen. *Default value: <full screen width>*
- `--screen-height integer` The height of the subscreen. *Default value: <full screen height>*

Comment: If you don't have nc (Windows) "vlc --one-instance vlc://quit" will also send a quit command to the remote control

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated. I don't know how the `quit` command (delivered through the remote control interface) worked in 2014, but now (VLC media player 2.2.2 on my Ubuntu 16.04) you must send the `stop` and `shutdown` commands (`quit` simply disconnects from the RC interface). Besides, it seems that interrupting the screen-capturing VLC process with CTRL-C is handled by VLC gracefully (using the verb **kill** for CTRL-C is an overkill). Also, it should be noted that the `--dummy-quiet` and `--rc-quiet` options are Windows-specific.

Comment: Vlc *can* handle the SIGINT and if it is written correctly, it closes the video stream on SIGINT correctly, *not* resulting a damaged video file.

Comment: this example not work for vlc 3.0.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. `--extraintf rc` has been replaced by `--extraintf oldrc`. and some other parameters (such as `--dummy-quiet`) isn't supported too. [this videolan wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/screen/) shows that `--screen-mouse-image` is used **only** for windows. I can't find a solution for mouse pointer image.

Answer (score 1):

**Screen capture** on terminal or iterm on Mac OS **2019**:

Add an alias to you `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` for VLC:

`alias vlc='/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC'`

Then add this function to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```sh
screencapture(){
vlc \
-I dummy screen://\
--dummy-quiet \
--screen-follow-mouse \
--screen-mouse-image="/Users/YOUR_HOME_DIR/Desktop/awesome.jpg" \
--screen-left=0 --screen-top=0 --screen-width=1280 --screen-height=720 \
--no-video :screen-fps=15 :screen-caching=300 \
--sout "#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,fps=5,scale=1,acodec=none}:duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='/Users/YOUR_HOME_DIR/Desktop/Screencapture $(date +%Y-%m-%d) at $(date +%H.%M.%S).mp4'}}"
}
```

Open a new terminal session and do: `screencapture`

When done do `CTRl + C` to stop the function.

That's it find the files in your Desktop folder example:

`Screencapture 2019-01-04 at 09.57.42.mp4`

Videos will be 1280x720 but you can customize this function however you like.

Comment: Also works for Ubuntu but I cut out the two mouse lines because I wasn't sure what they did.

Comment: Well --screen-follow-mouse flag will make the "camera" follow the mouse during the recording so to speak. And --screen-mouse-image="...image path..." uses an image as the mouse cursor.

Comment: The whole screen is being recorded so nothing special needed for mouse. Sound doesn't record though (default output audio device) so I'm thinking something like this needs to be added: `acodec=mp4a,ab=96,channels=2,samplerate=44100` but can't find an example to include sound.

Comment: Exactly, the `--screen-follow-mouse` flag is only useful if `--screen-width` and `--screen-height` are set to be smaller than full screen otherwise there is nothing to follow. BTW: if you do find a solution for the audio please share I'm curious now.

Comment: The sound issue is complicated. So far I've managed to route system output sounds into the microphone with `pavucontrol` which I think is a good first step.

Comment: After a couple of hours I threw in the towel and used **Simple Screen Recorder** instead. It's actually quite... simple.

Answer (score 0):

Important if you're on windows:

```
,... --rc-host localhost:8082
```

Doesn't work you'Ve to use local host ip otherwise it won't work. Use 127.0.0.1 instead:

```
,... --rc-host 127.0.0.1:8082
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change quit command on my machine (WIN 10):

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8082))
s.sendall('quit\n'.encode())
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a simple approach you don't need to deal with **TCP sockets/Unix Sockets.**

**Step1:**
First open Vlc ->Tools ->Preferences 
Under **Interface Tab** make sure you check "Allow only one Instance".

If you don't find it using above method then search for **instance** in **Advance Preference Tab** 
Then check Allow only one instance.

This helps you to prevent starting new recording and it allows you to keep track the existing recording.

**Step2:**
To start Recording use this command

```
vlc screen:// --qt-start-minimized :screen-fps=5 :run-time=30 :quiet :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb072}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst="C:\Users\**admin**\Desktop\screencast.mp4"}
```

**Step3:**
To save and Stop the existing record use

```
vlc://quit
```

**Note: Make sure to check the path before you use this commands**

Answer (score 0):

### To get audio on a Windows box

- To record with sound:

> vlc "dshow://" ":dshow-vdev=screen-capture-recorder" ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mpgv,acodec=mpga}:file{dst=*myscreencapture.mp4*}"

- To stop recording:

> Press PAUSE followed by CONTROL-F4

- Use "transform-type" filter to play, if it is inverted:

> vlc --transform-type=vflip "*myscreencapture.mp4*"