# How to make screenshots from TS video stream?

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, screenshot

I would like to make screenshots each 1 minutes from the video stream. The video stream is provided as [m3u8 file](http://cam.l-invest.ru/nagatinskaya4/tracks-v1/index.m3u8):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:112076
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2019-03-19T16:16:53Z
#EXTINF:6.000, 2019/03/19/16/16/53-06000.ts
#EXTINF:6.000, 2019/03/19/16/16/59-06000.ts
#EXTINF:6.000, 2019/03/19/16/17/05-06000.ts
#EXTINF:6.000, 2019/03/19/16/17/11-06000.ts
```

I found a library to parse it - https://github.com/globocom/m3u8. But I don't understand how I can convert this TS video stream to single jpeg file.
Am I supposed to

1. download TS file
2. find needed frame
3. extract it
4. delete ts file?

Should I use [OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames) or is there any easier solution?

use OpenV

Comment: Do you want every image in the video, or only one image?

Comment: One image each minute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a job for [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).
To capture a frame from a [playlist](http://cam.l-invest.ru/nagatinskaya4/tracks-v1/index.m3u8) every minute, you can use:

```
ffmpeg -i "http://cam.l-invest.ru/nagatinskaya4/tracks-v1/index.m3u8" -vf fps=1/60 invest.ru_%04d.jpg -hide_banner
```

The above will produce:

```
invest.ru_0001.jpg
```

[image: invest.ru_0001.jpg]

```
invest.ru_0002.jpg
```

[image: invest.ru_0002.jpg]

and so on... once every 60″

---

**Notes**:

1. `invest.ru_0002.jpg` was taken exactly 60″ after `invest.ru_0001.jpg`, as you can see in the upper-right timestamp.
2. `-vf` indicates `ffmpeg` to use a video filter `fps=1/60`, so it will extract one frame every 60″ ([src](https://www.bugcodemaster.com/article/extract-images-frame-frame-video-file-using-ffmpeg)).
3. The output format and filename structure can be changed if needed (ex: [`%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23006062/797495)). Please check the `ffmpeg` [image2 docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) for available options.

Comment: Thank you! Can I do the same with ffmpeg version 2.0.2? This is the version pre-installed on my old Synology NAS. It doesn't support hide_banner argument and if I remove it, it says `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'invest.ru_%04d.jpg'. invest.ru_%04d.jpg: Invalid argument`.

Comment: You're very welcome @LA_. The version of ffmpeg (windows) I used for the answer is **4.1**: `ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers`. You can grab the latest version at https://ffmpeg.org/download.html. If possible, use the latest, it should work as expected.

Comment: I am afraid I can not upgrade built-in utility. Or, if I can, I will have to compile it for my NAS. But anyway - you helped me a lot, many thanks!

Comment: `ffmpeg` is very flexible regarding installation, by this I mean that you can compile it from source with just the *plugins* you want, this way it doesn't get heavy on the system, also, because you aren't doing conversion to another format, the cpu load should be insignificant. GL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use VLC to do that.

*EDIT: looks very similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1379361/vlc-and-m3u8-file.*
*The following answer might not work for your file format (unless higher versions of VLC work correctly ...). May be have a look to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11508/how-do-i-play-m3u8-files) which might give you some more insight*

*To my knowledge, VLC works fines with TS files/streams*

---

**Once you have a TS file, you should be able to use vlc to perform your screenshots.**

According to [this link](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=66941) and to [this SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084098/vlc-screen-capture-using-terminal), one can launch VLC and make it perform screen captures.
And according to [VLC documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Make_thumbnails/), it seems possible.

Should work on win/linux/mac.

*I do have tested it yet, I need to reach my personal computer to do that.*

Quoting:

> With new VLC versions (VLC 1.1.0 and above), the thumbnails are generated with scene video filter
>
> `vlc C:\video\to\process.mp4 --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --start-time=10 --stop-time=11 --scene-format=png --scene-ratio=24 --scene-prefix=snap --scene-path=C:\path\for\snapshots\ vlc://quit`
>
> If you want to get rid of the sound you can add "--aout=dummy" next to "--vout=dummy".
>
> For older VLC versions (1.0.0 and below) the same can be done with image output module
>
> `vlc C:\video\to\process.mp4 -V image --start-time 0 --stop-time 1 --image-out-format jpg --image-out-ratio 24 --image-out-prefix snap vlc://quit`
>
> What it does:
>
> When VLC media player runs it 'plays' the video for one second without actually showing the video on screen, and then quits, leaving us with a file named 'snap000000.jpg', containing an image of the first frame of the video.